# How can I explain this timezone behavior of Date?

Tags: javascript

For the JS `Date` object, ISO 8601 date strings that specify a time are treated as local (Note 2, [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date)).

If we assume the locale for a machine is configured to be in England, and the current date in England is 23rd September 2022, the current local time zone (?) is UTC+0100 (British Summer Time).

If I supply a date without timezone that would in my locale ordinarily be in summertime (so in BST), then `Date` treats the string as BST (unsurprising).

If I supply a date without timezone that would, in my locale, ordinarily be outside of summertime (so in UTC), then `Date` treats the string as UTC (surprising, as UTC is not currently my local timezone).

```
new Date('2022-06-01T12:00:00') // Wed Jun 01 2022 12:00:00 GMT+0100 (British Summer Time)
new Date('2022-01-01T12:00:00') // Sat Jan 01 2022 12:00:00 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time) (! - my local timezone is BST, not GMT!)
```

How do I explain this? Is BST a time zone, or is it something else (eg. a mode of a timezone)?

Comment: I don't see any UTC output in your snippet. I see GMT, which is the British winter (normal) time, and totally appropriate for your local time zone?

Comment: I thought UTC and GMT were the same thing. But it appears that [GMT is a timezone and UTC is a time standard](https://www.worldtimeserver.com/learn/utc-vs-gmt/)? Is UTC+1 (or UTC+0) a timezone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timezone `BST`/`British Summer Time` does not exit on Jan 1st. The areas that use `BST` on the summer use `GMT` during the winter.

Comment: So the rule is: use the local time zone if it exists on that date; otherwise use UTC (or something else)?

Comment: Not UTC. It will use the correct local timezone you're using at that date. E.g. for me `new Date('2022-06-01T12:00:00')` is `Wed Jun 01 2022 12:00:00 GMT+0300 (Eastern European Summer Time)` and `new Date('2022-01-01T12:00:00')` is `Sat Jan 01 2022 12:00:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)`.

Comment: Timezone UTC+1 always exists AFAIK. So does this mean that BST and UTC+1 are two different timezones?

Comment: Yes, they are indeed distinct.

Comment: So some timezones are only in existence intermittently?

Comment: Yes, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_Summer_Time ("This time zone is only used for DST. For the rest of the year, GMT is used.")

Answer (score 0):

For ISO 8601 date-times without a defined time zone, JavaScript does not assume the time zone to be the same as the time zone locally in effect, it assumes the local geographic location and then chooses the time zone that would be in effect at the specified wall-clock time in that location. Or something.